# arrays having numeric values separated by a dot

Tags: php, arrays, compare

Suppose I have following 2 arrays

```
$array_a = array("01.03.04.45.06");

$array_b = array("01.05","07.09.12","01.45","09.11","08.09.32","79.02.03.12","02.03")
```

$array_a contains a string with 5 numbers separated by a dot while
$array_b contains various strings of 2 max 5 numbers separated by a dot.

I need to compare $array_a and $array_b and search and returning TRUE if there are min. 2 numbers of any key of array $array_b in array $array_a

For example in the case above the comparation should return
TRUE because numbers in $array_b[3] ( 01.45 ) are inside $array_a .

Any way to do this comparation ?
I tried using array_intersect and array_diff but no success.

Comment: There is no 11 on `$array_a`

Comment: sorry , corrected 01.45

Comment: $array_b[3]  is  01.45 , 01 and 45 are in $array_a .

Comment: You'll need to write this; array functions are not going to help you just like that because what you have now is a string and an array of strings.

Comment: Somehow I get a strong impression of an interview question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array_filter` to the list of **match array elements**

```
$array_a = array("01.03.04.45.06");

$array_b = array("01.05","07.09.12","01.45","09.11","08.09.32","79.02.03.12","02.03");

//Make $array_a array
$array_a = explode( ".", $array_a[0] );

$result = array_filter($array_b,function( $var ) use($array_a){
    $temp = explode( ".", $var );
    $count = 0;

    foreach( $temp as $x ) if ( in_array( $x, $array_a ) ) $count++;
    if ( $count >= 2 ) return true;
});


echo "<pre>";
print_r( $result );
echo "</pre>";
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [2] => 01.45
)
```

Doc: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

---

If you want to return a **bool only**, you can use `array_reduce`

```
$array_a = array("01.03.04.45.06");

$array_b = array("01.05","07.09.12","01.45","09.11","08.09.32","79.02.03.12","02.03");

//Make $array_a array
$array_a = explode( ".", $array_a[0] );

$result = array_reduce($array_b,function( $carry, $var ) use($array_a){
    $temp = explode( ".", $var );
    $count = 0;

    foreach( $temp as $x ) if ( in_array( $x, $array_a ) ) $count++;
    if ( $count >= 2 || $carry ) return true;
});


echo "<pre>";
print_r( $result );
echo "</pre>";
```

This will return to `true`

Doc: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php

---

**Update:** You can use `array_values` to convert associative array to basic/numerical array.

```
$array_b[]["BA.CA.FI.GE.MI"]="01.08"; 
$array_b[]["BA.GE.MI.NA.RM"]="02.04"; 
$array_b[]["BA.MI.NA.RM.VE"]="01.45";

$array_a = array("01.03.04.45.06");

//Make $array_a array
$array_a = explode( ".", $array_a[0] );

$result = array_filter($array_b,function( $var ) use($array_a){
    $var = array_values($var);
    $temp = explode( ".", $var[0] );
    $count = 0;
    foreach( $temp as $x ) if ( in_array( $x, $array_a ) ) $count++;
    if ( $count >= 2 ) return true;
});

echo "<pre>";
print_r( $result );
echo "</pre>";
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [BA.MI.NA.RM.VE] => 01.45
        )

)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php

Comment: Your first solution is ok for me. However I have a problem I had to change the array_b as follow

$array_b[]["BA.CA.FI.GE.MI"]="01.08";
$array_b[]["BA.GE.MI.NA.RM"]="02.04";
$array_b[]["BA.MI.NA.RM.VE"]="01.45";

can you tell me how to change your code to work with the new array ? Thank you.

Comment: @graziano Please check my updated answer. Please let me know how it goes.